# Copy cell values from one excel workbooks sheet to another when a cell value matches in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excels workbooks, let's say, wb01 and wb02. Suppose they have only one sheet, sh01 and sh02 respectively.

I need to synchronize sheets (sh01 and sh02) by copying the cell values (name and surname columns) from sh01 to sh02 when "Id" column match.

**Example**

**sh01 in wb01**

```
Id | name     | surname  | Dept
10 | John     | McCoy    | Logistics
21 | Liam     | Alloy    | Administration
40 | Peter    | Gregor   | Finance
42 | Albert   | Kein     | Business
50 | Kelly    | Braxton  | Logistics
60 | Isabella | O'Neill  | Finance
```

**sh02 in wb02**

```
Id | name   | surname   | ext.
10 | David  | McCoy     | 1004
23 | Bren   | Summer    | 1230
40 | George | Brown     | 2400
42 | Astrid | Anderson  | 3312
50 | Kelly  | Braxton   | 1139
51 | Evelyn | Connor    | 4532
```

I do not need to copy these cell values from sh02 to sh01, only from sh01 to sh02.
Also if "Id" cell value exists on wb01 but not in sh2, cell values name and surname should be copied to sh02 as a new row and the rest of fields must be kept empty/blank in sh02.

Taken into account above two sheets, after copying process, sh02 must be as below:

```
Id | name     | surname   | ext.
10 | John     | McCoy     | 1004
21 | Liam     | Alloy     | 
23 | Bren     | Summer    | 1230
40 | Peter    | Gregor    | 2400
42 | Albert   | Kein      | 3312
50 | Kelly    | Braxton   | 1139
51 | Evelyn   | Connor    | 4532
60 | Isabella | O'Neill   |
```

This copy process should be done on demand, I mean, when user clicks a button from sh02 in wb02. On button click, a macro in sh02 will be executed to start the copying process from sh01 to sh02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've literally not provided any code that you've attempted to use to do this, more people would gladly help if you would have at least attempted to code it...
Nonetheless, you did not provide your sheet names, here is some code you can put to the test.

```
Sub CopyValue

Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long, counter As Integer

counter = 0
Set wb1 = Workbooks("wb01")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("wb02")
lastrow = wb1.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = wb2.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To lastrow
    For y = 2 To lastrow2
    If wb1.Sheets("abc").Cells(x,1).Value = wb2.Sheets("def").Cells(y,1).Value Then
        wb2.Sheets("def").Cells(y,2).Value =    wb1.Sheets("abc").Cells(x,2).Value
        wb2.Sheets("def").Cells(y,3).Value =    wb1.Sheets("abc").Cells(x,3).Value
    Else
        counter= counter +1
        wb2.Sheets("def").Cells(lastrow+counter,1).Value = wb1.sheets("abc").Cells(x,1).Value
        wb2.Sheets("def").Cells(lastrow+counter,2).Value = wb1.sheets("abc").Cells(x,2).Value
        wb2.Sheets("def").Cells(lastrow+counter,3).Value = wb1.sheets("abc").Cells(x,3).Value
    End If
Next y
Next x
End Sub
```